# Renice command is linux

Tags: linux

I want to change the priority of all httpd processes in Linux using renice command . Command mentioned doesn't work 
renice -n 10 {pgrep httpd}

Please provide thoughts on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where the curley brackets come from.  try

```
 renice -n 10 `pgrep httpd`
```

The pgrep httpd will list the process ID'd for httpd and renice will change the priority of those PID's.   In order for the ID's to be parsed to renice, that command needs to be run - and you can use backticks for that.

Comment: [It](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) [looks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/108618) [like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118438/108618) `$()` should be preferred.